# Postgresql WITH-clause: sequentially or nested

Tags: postgresql

I must select CTE by the value of the window function. How, in terms of CPU, memory, choose? sequentially?

```
WITH t1 AS(
  SELECT col1, col2, row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY col1, col2 ORDER BY col3) rn
  FROM tbl
),
t2 AS(
  SELECT col1, col2
  FROM t1
  WHERE rn = 1
)
SELECT *
FROM t2;
```

or nested

```
WITH t2 AS(
  WITH t1 AS(
    SELECT col1, col2, row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY col1, col2 ORDER BY col3) rn
    FROM tbl
  )
  SELECT col1, col2
  FROM t1
  WHERE rn = 1
)
SELECT *
FROM t2;
```

`EXPLAIN ANALYZE` is not clear. `WHERE rn = 1` in a separate CTE, because this data will be needed in several CTEs. By the execution time is almost no different.

Comment: Are the query plans even different? Can you post them?

Comment: You will be faster if you don't use `WITH` and do `LIMIT 1`.